# Extend the onchange_employee_id method from hr_payslip class

Tags: python, odoo-8

how do i extend the onchange_employee_id method from hr_payslip class, i have tried with this code :

```
import openerp
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp import api, fields, models, _, SUPERUSER_ID

class hr_payslip(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.payslip'


    @api.onchange('employee_id')
    def onchange_employee_id(self, date_from, date_to, employee_id=False, contract_id=False):
      *#my logic here* 
       return {}
```

and i got an error like this :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 544, in _handle_exception
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 581, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 317, in _call_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 314, in checked_call
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 810, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 410, in response_wrap
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 944, in call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 399, in old_api
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5989, in onchange
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5881, in _onchange_eval
TypeError: onchange_employee_id() takes at most 5 arguments (8 given)
```

and iam using odoo v8, thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy cut the def line from original function

```
def onchange_employee_id(self, cr, uid, ids, date_from, date_to, employee_id=False, contract_id=False, context=None):
        res=super(hr_payslip, self).onchange_employee_id(self, cr, uid, ids, date_from, date_to, employee_id=False, contract_id=False, context=None)

        # Add your code here
        return res
```

Comment: ah thanks for the answer, even i have found the solution, but my solution is same as you. iam using the old api now

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to use cr,uid,context as arguments on your function and In new odoo api method you can invoke the onchange using decorators. so you should remove **@api.model** or use **@api.onchange('employee_id')**  instead. if you are using decorators , then you should remove **cr, uid, ids,context** which is not needed and we can access those form **self**.

If you need to extend the onchange method one option is to redefine the function in inherited model **'hr.payslip'** and define a function as below

```
@api.onchange('employee_id')
def onchange_employee_id(self):#gave extra arguments if any
      *logic*
      return {}
```

Comment: should i remove the _inherit = 'hr.payslip' ? cus i got error like this with that defined function above `TypeError: onchange_employee_id() takes exactly 1 argument (8 given)`

Comment: I only says to remove cr,uid,ids and context, which is not need to use if we are using decorators, else you only need to remove @api.model from your previous code

Comment: you dont need to update my code as your answer, I just gave you an example. Where in your Original code, ie first attempt, there you only remove the @api.model decorator